# How can I keep items in ComboBox after close the application

Tags: vb.net, combobox

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnAddCat_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddCat.Click

    If txtAdd.Text <> "" Then
        comboBox1.Items.Add(txtAdd.Text)
        txtAdd.Clear()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Fill the blanket")
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

If user close application should see the items but there is no items
Can anyone help?
thanks

Comment: You want the user to be able to see the items once the application is launched (started)?

Comment: Yes exactly but user have already add items before and the application's been closed and now it is launched again!
(P.S. Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Ok, in that case, like Karl and Steven mentioned, you would have to connect the application to a data store system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the application to remember the value the next time it is run, you will need to save the value to disk.  There are many different options for how to do that (e.g. text file, XML, database, registry), but for simple tasks, I'd recommend just using the built-in `Settings` feature.

To use the `Settings` feature, first you need to open your project properties screen.  Then select the `Settings` tab.  Add a new setting by typing in the name and selecting a data type.  For instance, you could type `MyItems` for the name, and then select `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` as the data type.  Then, in your code, you can read the current value of the setting like this (perhaps in your form's `Load` event handler):

```
For Each i As String In My.Settings.MyItems
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
Next
```

And then you could save the list to the setting, like this (perhaps in your form's `FormClosed` event handler):

```
My.Settings.MyItems.Clear()
For Each i As String In ComboBox1.Items
    My.Settings.MyItems.Add(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist the data to a data store (either the database or the file system) so that the next time the application runs, then it can check the data store and display the items to the user.